# how do i print print the numbers replacing "??"

Tags: android

Basically I'm trying to replace "?" by pressing any keypad button. For example, if the question shows as "0+1=?", I want "1" to replace the question mark.

My code for Java is:

```
package org.example.question;

import java.util.Random;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //variable for different questions
    int fnum0, snum0,fnum1, snum1,fnum2, snum2,fnum3, snum3,
    fnum4, snum4,fnum5, snum5,fnum6, snum6,fnum7, snum7,
    fnum8, snum8,fnum9, snum9, answer;


    //variable and type declaration for buttons and text
Button keyOne;
Button keyTwo;
Button keyThree;
Button keyFour;
Button keyFive;
Button keySix;
Button keySeven;
Button keyEight;
Button keyNine;
Button keyDel;
Button keyZero;
Button keyHash;
Button keySubtract;
TextView display;
TextView display1;
TextView answer0;
int question=0;
boolean q;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        //display text on screen

        display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Guess);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
        answer0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Answer);

        ///Code for correct and incorrect

        //assigning names to each keypad
        keyOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        keyTwo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        keyThree= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        keyFour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        keyFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
        keySix= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        keySeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        keyEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        keyNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        keyZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_0);
        keySubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        keyHash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
        keyDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

        //setting button to produce an event when each button is pressed
        keyOne.setOnClickListener(this);     keyTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     keyThree.setOnClickListener(this); 
        keyFour.setOnClickListener(this);    keyFive.setOnClickListener(this);     keySix.setOnClickListener(this);     
        keySeven.setOnClickListener(this);    keyEight.setOnClickListener(this);  keyNine.setOnClickListener(this);    
        keySubtract.setOnClickListener(this);   keyHash.setOnClickListener(this);  keyDel.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        switch(arg0.getId()){   
        case R.id.keypad_hash:

            //Generates random numbers
            fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            String str = ""; 

            //genrates random number between 0 to 9
            int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
            Log.d("debug", "operation value: " + operation);


            if(operation == 0)  
               str = fnum0+  "+"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 

            else if(operation == 1) 
               str = fnum0 +  "-"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 
            else if(operation == 2)  
               str = fnum0 +  "*"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??" ; 
            else  
               str = fnum0 +  "/"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 
            display.setText(str); 
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_1:
            if(q="?" )
            {
                display.setText("1");
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            break;

        case R.id.keypad_2:
            display.setText("2");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_3:
            display.setText("3");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_4:
            display.setText("4");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_5:
            display.setText("5");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_6:
            display.setText("6");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_7:
            display.setText("7");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_8:
            display.setText("8");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_9:
            display.setText("9");
            break;

        case R.id.delete:
            display.setText("");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_0:
            display.setText("0");
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_subtract:
            display.setText("-");
            break;   
        }   
     }
    public void requestFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

However at the moment its displaying the question "0+1="  but when I press one it removes the question and display "1" on its own on the screen.

UPDATE for ERROR

```
case R.id.keypad_1:

public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String str=null;
        switch(arg0.getId()){   
        case R.id.keypad_hash:

            //Generates random numbers
            fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 


            //genrates random number between 0 to 9
            int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
            Log.d("debug", "operation value: " + operation);


            if(operation == 0)  
               str = fnum0+  "+"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 

            else if(operation == 1) 
               str = fnum0 +  "-"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 
            else if(operation == 2)  
               str = fnum0 +  "*"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??" ; 
            else  
               str = fnum0 +  "/"  +  snum0+  "="+ "??"; 
            display.setText(str); 
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_1:
            if(str.equals("??"))
            {
                String str1 = display.getText().toString(); 
                display.setText(str1.replace("??", "1")); 
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            break;
```

The application is crashing now.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
display.setText("1");
```

write

```
display.setText(str.replace("??", "1"));
```

The replace method indicates that replace the "??" text on the str String with the "1" text, so searches the "??" text and replace it by the "1" text on this String.

To compare Strings should use equals method, for example instead of `str==?`, write:

```
str.equals("?");
```

Replace the code of the keypad_1 case for this one (deleting the if):

```
case R.id.keypad_1:
      String str1 = display.getText().toString(); 
      display.setText(str1.replace("??", "1")); 
break;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it gives the error "The local variable str may not have been initialized"

Comment: Define your str variable before the switch of the onClick method.

Comment: where you define "String str"? define it between "public void onClick(View arg0) {" line and "switch(arg0.getId()){" line.

Comment: i did on that exact location but now its giving me a different error on the if statement.... i will add the code for you to have a look

Comment: @sabadow Initialization and declaration are two very different things

Comment: @izkata, can u tell me where m going wrong, i did what sabadow told me, after i done acted on his solution the button 1 aint even working no more

Comment: the application is crashing now.. lol i will show you the whole part of the code

Comment: don't initialize to null: String str=new String(); But in the code that you post the check "if(str.equals("??"))" never will be true...

Comment: it worked mate.. thanks a lot.. could you explain me what that code actually does so that i can put  in comment coz i havea viva on it as well..

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain of the exact method calls required (it's been a while), but what you want to do is get the current text from the display, modify it, and re-display it.  I believe this will work:

```
String str = display.getText().toString();
display.setText(str.replace("??", "1"));
```

Comment: i have inserted that code and the application is crashing now... i hv upload the code section where i have inserted the above code... but still not working

Comment: @ahmedafzaal Don't just blindly copy code.  As I said, I'm uncertain of the method calls required - [take a look](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) at the API for TextView.  `getText()` returns a CharSequence, which needs to be turned into a String before using replace.

Comment: @ahmedafzaal Besides which, it looks like you were half-applying the other answer at the same time as this one.  It was crashing because of the `null.equals()` in the halfway-fixed update from that answer.